# Key Vault ipRules property as parameter issue

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add Firewall rules for Azure Key Vault using ARM templates. It works as expected if **ipRules** property in conjunction with multiple IPs are defined in template (not as parameter).

However, if I try to define it as parameter getting **"Bad JSON content found in the request."**

*Property defined in **Template** ("apiVersion": "2019-09-01"):*

```
    "kv-ipRules": {
       "type": "array",
       "metadata": {
            "description": "The address space (in CIDR notation) to use for the Azure Key Vault to be deployed as Firewall rules."
       }
    }

"networkAcls": {
                "defaultAction": "Deny",
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
                "virtualNetworkRules": [
                {
                    "id": "[concat(parameters('kv-virtualNetworks'), '/subnets/','kv-subnet')]",
                    "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                }
                ],
                "ipRules": "[parameters('kv-ipRules')]"
            }
```

*Property defined in **Parameters**:*

```
  "kv-ipRules": {
    "value": [
      "xx.xx.xx.xxx",
      "yy.yy.yy.yyy"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults?tabs=json#IPRule), I would use:

```
"kv-ipRules": {
    "value": [
    {
      "value": "xx.xx.xx.xxx"
    },
    {
      "value": "yy.yy.yy.yyy"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, that was simple. Thanks for help!